# Tangent space, a group and a manifold

Tags: group-theory, manifolds

Let G be a group with a smooth manifold structure and let $u:G\times G\rightarrow G$ be the smooth multiplication  defined by $(x, y)\mapsto xy$.

Question: Why is the Tangent map $T_{(e, e)}u$ given by $(X, Y)=X+Y$?

The hint is to look at the partial derivatives with respect to x and y. My Problem lies in the definition of the tangentspace and the computation of the derivative on a manifold. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a kind of "cheating" way to do this.

Consider the obvious embeddings $\iota_j:G\to G\times G$ where $\iota_1(g)=(g,1)$ and $\iota_2(g)=(1,g)$. Then, we obtain embeddings $(\iota_j)_\ast:T_e G\to T_{(e,e)}(G\times G)$. Taking the product yields an isomorphism $(\iota_1)_\ast\times(\iota_2)_\ast:T_e G\times T_e G\to T_{(e,e)}(G\times G)$.

So, now, note that just using the linearity of $u_\ast$ and the chain rule we obtain:

$$\begin{aligned}u_{\ast}(X,Y) &=u_{\ast}((\iota_1)_\ast(X)+(\iota_2)_\ast(Y))\\ &=u_{\ast}((\iota_1)_\ast(X))+u_{\ast}((\iota_2)_{\ast}(Y))\\ &=(u\circ \iota_1)_\ast(X)+(u\circ\iota_2)_\ast(Y)\\ &=(\text{id})_\ast(X)+\text{id}_\ast(Y)\\ &=X+Y\end{aligned}$$